# Using axis units to set the aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to define the aspect ratio of a 2D plot in Matplotlib, using axis units with pre-defined conversions. In the past, I have done this manually by calculating the desired aspect ratio, but this was before I knew about the axis `units` capabilities in Matplotlib. It would seem that Matplotlib should be able to use `units` to accomplish the same thing automatically, but it looks as if `units` are not used in computing aspect ratios. I wanted to check here if that is the case, or if I'm missing something.

Here's an example to explain what I mean. It's not what I want this for, but it is a fully-worked example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from basic_units import cm, inch

def gauss(sigma=0.1):
    x = y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.4, 10)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(y, x)
    return np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2) / (2 * sigma**2))

z = np.tile(gauss(), (5, 5))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(z, extent=[-2.5,2.5,-2.5,2.5])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_units(cm)
ax.yaxis.set_units(inch)

ax.set_xlim(-2.5*cm, 2.5*cm)
ax.set_ylim(-2.5*inch, 2.5*inch)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from basic_units import cm, inch

def gauss(sigma=0.1):
    x = y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.4, 10)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(y, x)
    return np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2) / (2 * sigma**2))

z = np.tile(gauss(), (5, 5))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(z, extent=[-2.5,2.5,-2.5,2.5])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_units(cm)
ax.yaxis.set_units(inch)

ax.set_xlim(-2.5*cm, 2.5*cm)
ax.set_ylim(-2.5*inch, 2.5*inch)
ax.set_xlabel(cm)
ax.set_ylabel(inch)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

To run this, you also need [basic_units.py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_downloads/0f0fd288c7d4a6a16f4835b96343f597/basic_units.py)

[image]

I was hoping the physical aspect ratio would be 2.54, after setting it to 'equal', but it's not. My question therefore is if there is a way to configure Matplotlib so that an aspect ratio of 'equal' is adjusted by the conversion factor between units, without having to compute the ratio by hand.

Comment: Looking at `basic_unit.py`, there doesn't seem to be an inherent value to inches or centimeters. What might work is to work in all centimeters or inches and then use the conversion method to convert one of the axes to the other.

Comment: @jared, Lines 283 to 286 in `basic_unit.py` contain the conversions from inches to cm and back.

Comment: @RayOsborn Yes, if you computed everything in inches and then converted the x-values to centimeters (or do everything in cm and convert the y-values to inches) so the values were consistent, then using equal aspect ratio would work. If you don't want to do that, then just set the aspect ratio as the ratio between inches and centimeters, i.e. `ax.set_aspect(1/2.54)`. If you want to use the conversion methods, then `ax.set_aspect(cm.convert_value_to(1, inch))`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, I have rephrased the original question so that it doesn't look as if I only want opinions.